# Regex в excel. Как работают vba скрипты

Tags: excel, vba

Есть таблица [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу разбить ФИО на Фамиилию Имя Отчество. Интересно сделать это через регулярки и vba.
Код скрипта:

```
Public Function RegExpExtract(Text As String, Pattern As String, Item As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = Pattern
    regex.Global = True
    If regex.Test(Text) Then
        Set matches = regex.Execute(Text)
        RegExpExtract = matches.Item(Item - 1)
        Exit Function
    End If
ErrHandl:
    RegExpExtract = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Насколько я разобрался, функция RegExpExtract - принимает три аргумента: строку, паттерн, и номер_нужного_совпадения. Регулярное выражение "[А-Я-а-я]*" как раз разбивает строку на три подстроки,которые соответствуют имени,фамилии и отчеству. То-есть,если я передам третьим параметром "2"- получу имя,"3" - отчество.С единичкой работает,возвращается Фамилия. С 2 и 3 - нет. Я не особо понимаю структуру vba скрипта, и где строчка,ответственная за возвращения подстроки. Подскажите пожалуйста,как модифицировать код для моих нужд. Спасибо. P.s Понимаю,что это решение из разряда изобретения велосипеда,но все таки интересно разобраться в этом. Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Может пригодится - Google tables -  поддерживает регулярки "из коробки " 
+ В экселе есть функция разбить строки в столбце по пробелам из одного столбца получите три с именем отчеством фамилией аналогично .split(' ')
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/131qQeOkba2rYY8IumEYaX9hvbkUCYVnnxCgOpbXe3iM/htmlview#gid=1951598321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возврат значений в функциях VBA происходит через зарезервированную одноименную внешнюю переменную. В представленной функции это здесь:

```
Public Function RegExpExtract(Text As String, Pattern As String, Item As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = Pattern
    regex.Global = True
    If regex.Test(Text) Then
        Set matches = regex.Execute(Text)
        Rem Вот здесь возврат значения через переменную RegExpExtract 
        RegExpExtract = matches.Item(Item - 1)
        Exit Function
    End If
ErrHandl:
    Rem И вот здесь тоже возврат значения через переменную RegExpExtract 
    RegExpExtract = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Проверил работу представленной функции - все работает ожидаемым образом. Здесь все нормально.

У вас ошибка в паттерне. `*` - обозначает несколько символов или их отсутствие. Таким образом, пробел так же определяется как валидная последовательность символов. Вам нужно указать следующий паттер `[А-Яа-я]+`, где `+` - определяет от одного и более символов.

Проверить работу можно следующим образом:

```
Sub test()
    Const pattern As String = "[А-Яа-я]+"
    Const fio As String = "Иванов Петр Сидорович"
    Debug.Print RegExpExtract(fio, pattern, 1)
    Debug.Print RegExpExtract(fio, pattern, 2)
    Debug.Print RegExpExtract(fio, pattern, 3)
End Sub
```

Результаты вывода можно увидеть в окне Immediate

```
Иванов
Петр
Сидорович
```